# Evaluate R function stored in column that references other column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have the following dataset:

```
my.df <- data.frame(my_function=rep(c("Var1+Var 2","Var 2-Var1","(Var 2-(Var 2-Var1))/Var 2"), 1),
                    `Var1`=rep(1:1,3), 
                    `Var 2`=rep(5:5,3), check.names = FALSE)

my.df
#                  my_function Var1 Var 2
# 1                 Var1+Var 2    1     5
# 2                 Var 2-Var1    1     5
# 3 (Var 2-(Var 2-Var1))/Var 2    1     5
```

And I want to use column named `my_function` to calculate the values for each row into a new column called `outcome`

The `outcome` would be: `1+5=6`,`5-1=4`,`(5-(5-1))/5=0.2` for each of the rows.

**EDIT**
Correct answers also reference the following original dataset:

```
my.df <- data.frame(my_function=rep(c("1000+2000","2000-1000","(2000-(2000-1000))/2000"), 1), `1000`=rep(1:1,3), `2000`=rep(5:5,3))
```

Comment: This would be massively easier if your code used valid R variable names instead of numbers. — But, more importantly: please provide some more background information: why are you doing this, where is the data coming from, etc? This is important for finding the most appropriate solution in your code (especially since evaluating arbitrary code provided externally is usually a *big* no-no, for reasons of efficiency as well as safety).

Comment: Hi Konrad - I appreciate the help. I updated the calculation. I moved from 1000 and 2000 to "Var1" and "Var 2". "Var 2" is by choice.

Comment: Is it always 2 vars?

Comment: It has a space because I have many different named variables in a wide format and the calculations are considerably more complex and I need it to work for more complex names. Basically the function names are fixed and I cannot change them.

Comment: @zx8754 No there are ~100 variables.

Comment: I think you need `check.names = FALSE)` in your original dataset example, to avoid X prefixes.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to show the whole equaiton as a result `1+5=6` or just the actual result on the righthand side of the equation `6`?

Comment: your function is a string, why not keep it as a function?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through *my_function*, then loop through column names *gsub* with value, finally *evil* parse:

```
vars <- colnames(my.df)[ -1 ]

sapply(seq(nrow(my.df)), function(i){
  res <- my.df[i, 1]
  for(v in vars){
    res <- gsub(v, my.df[i, v], res, fixed = TRUE)
  }
  eval(parse(text = res))
})
# [1] 6.0 4.0 0.2
```

Note:

```
fortunes::fortune("answer is parse")
# If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#    -- Thomas Lumley
#       R-help (February 2005)
```

Comment: I imagine you meant “eval parse,” but “*evil* parse” is consistent with all the warnings against arbitrary text evaluation in this thread.

Comment: @zephryl yes...

Comment: For the lolz I upvoted. I don't usually use `parse` but when I do, it is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

```r
my.df <- data.frame(my_function=rep(c("1000+2000","2000-1000","(2000-(2000-1000))/2000"), 1), `1000`=rep(1:1,3), `2000`=rep(5:5,3))

my.df
#>               my_function X1000 X2000
#> 1               1000+2000     1     5
#> 2               2000-1000     1     5
#> 3 (2000-(2000-1000))/2000     1     5

my.df$my_function = gsub("1000", "X1000", my.df$my_function)
my.df$my_function = gsub("2000", "X2000", my.df$my_function)

my.df$outcome = sapply(split(my.df, 1:NROW(my.df)), function(x)
  eval(str2lang(x$my_function),x))

my.df
#>                   my_function X1000 X2000 outcome
#> 1                 X1000+X2000     1     5     6.0
#> 2                 X2000-X1000     1     5     4.0
#> 3 (X2000-(X2000-X1000))/X2000     1     5     0.2
```

However you should read the comments since there are security concerns about evaluating arbitrary code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391779/6912817 for case.

Answer (score 0):

As expressed in the comments, I don't love parsing code from text, especially is the code text was generated through some user input. Here is, in my opinion, a safe way to evaluate these expressions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my.df <- data.frame(my_function=rep(c("1000+2000","2000-1000","(2000-(2000-1000))/2000"), 1), `1000`=rep(1:1,3), `2000`=rep(5:5,3))

my.df |>
  mutate(sub_function = pmap_chr(list(my_function, X1000, X2000),
                                 ~gsub(pattern = "1000", 
                                      replacement = ..2,
                                      x = ..1) |> 
                                   gsub(pattern = "2000",
                                       replacement = ..3)),
         eval = map_chr(sub_function, ~as.character(Ryacas::yac_symbol(.x))))
#>               my_function X1000 X2000 sub_function eval
#> 1               1000+2000     1     5          1+5    6
#> 2               2000-1000     1     5          5-1    4
#> 3 (2000-(2000-1000))/2000     1     5  (5-(5-1))/5  1/5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rlang and `purrr::pmap_dbl()`:

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)

my.df$outcome <- pmap_dbl(
  my.df,
  \(my_function, Var1, Var2, ...) {
    eval(parse_expr(enexpr(my_function)))
  }
)

my.df
```

```
              my_function Var1 Var2 outcome
1               Var1+Var2    1    5     6.0
2               Var2-Var1    1    5     4.0
3 (Var2-(Var2-Var1))/Var2    1    5     0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `bquote` and `deparse`. Since your example data uses integers I first transform those to `numeric` to get rid of the `L` in the output.

```r
my.df <- data.frame(
  my_function = rep(c("Var1+Var 2",
                      "Var 2-Var1",
                      "(Var 2-(Var 2-Var1))/Var 2"),
                    1),
  `Var1` = rep(1:1,3),
  `Var 2` = rep(5:5,3),
  check.names = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

my.df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Var"), as.double)) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(outcome = str_replace_all(my_function,
                                   "(Var\\s{0,1}[0-9]+)",
                                   '.(.data[["\\1"]])') %>% 
           paste0("bquote(", ., ")") %>%
           str2lang %>%
           eval %>%
           list,
         outcome = paste0(deparse(outcome), " = ", res = eval(outcome)))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   my_function                 Var1 `Var 2` outcome              
#>   <chr>                      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                
#> 1 Var1+Var 2                     1       5 1 + 5 = 6            
#> 2 Var 2-Var1                     1       5 5 - 1 = 4            
#> 3 (Var 2-(Var 2-Var1))/Var 2     1       5 (5 - (5 - 1))/5 = 0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>