# How to remove this <environment: 0x00000261b409ba50> from a string evaluated and parsed in R?

Tags: r, function, parsing, eval

Noob question here. Just want to ask how to remove this environment prompt in the console of RStudio when printing a function (originally a String) that was parsed and evaluated using parse() and eval(), respectively?

Originally, I have this string that was inserted in a list:

`final = "function (x) -115.2278 + 0.6304 * x + 5e-04 * x^2 + 0 * x^3 + 0 * x^4 + 0 * x^5"`

But when I use parse and eval to it, it becomes:

`$Polynomial`
`function (x) -115.2278 + 0.6304 * x + 5e-04 * x^2 + 0 * x^3 + 0 * x^4 + 0 * x^5`
`<environment: 0x00000261b611f2e0>`

I expect the output to look like this:

`$Polynomial`
`function (x) -115.2278 + 0.6304 * x + 5e-04 * x^2 + 0 * x^3 + 0 * x^4 + 0 * x^5`

I hope you can help me solve this problem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
`cat(paste0(deparse(your_variable), collapse="\n")`

or

Set the function environment to globalenv

```r
a <- function() NULL
print(a)
#> function() NULL

environment(a) <- new.env()
print(a)
#> function() NULL
#> <environment: 0x000001ff77e5c3e8>

environment(a) <- globalenv()
print(a)
#> function() NULL
```

But **beware of what are you doing**. Setting the environment to a function could let it broken if it refers to objects in their original environment.
Also it is not a well practice to evaluate arbitrary string code from external sources. See [Safely evaluating arithmetic expressions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369913/safely-evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-in-r)