# How to transform an equation writen in a string/character to its actual value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Say, for example, you have the following **string**:

```
"(1+1)*2"
```

And you want to transform it to its actual value (4, which comes from evaluating the equation in the string) in numeric.

I've trayed several ways, using `eval()` or `as.formula()`, but haven't figured it out yet. Any guess?

Comment: Nor as.numeric, I find...hmmh. @zephryl, could you expand on 'sanitizing inputs', are we talking SQL injection or the like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval(parse())` as follows:

```
eval(parse(text = "(1+1)*2"))
# 4
```

Note you shouldn’t use this in a public-facing application without sanitizing inputs.

Comment: And might you expand on sanitizing inputs, as cautionary tales are always useful as choices are made in approaches, i.e. what would sanitizing look like in this instance?

Comment: Without scary details, something like `eval(parse(text = "code.to.kill.the.computer()"))` may do harm to your computer. An input with only numbers, brackets, and arithmetic operators is probably safe.

Comment: @Chris [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18369913/17303805) has more info on potential issues and solutions. tbh I’m not super knowledgeable in this area beyond knowing you should generally be careful with anything evaluating arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

`parse(text = "...")` is equivalent to `str2lang("...")`.

```r
eval(str2lang("(1+1)*2"))

# [1] 4
```