# Pass function as argument to Rscript through terminal

Tags: r, terminal, parameter-passing

I want to pass a function as an argument of Rscript through Posit Terminal to evaluate a mathematical problem.

This is a reproducible example, where a script named `imp.R` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
x <- args[1]
f <- as.function(alist(x=, args[2]))
paste("The function is:", f(x))
```

With a Terminal call from [Posit Page](https://posit.cloud/) as:

```
/cloud/project$ Rscript imp.R "c(1,2,3)" sin(x^2)
```

I've got the error message: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token` ('`

But with: `Rscript imp.R "c(1,2,3)" "sin(x^2)"` it returns: `"The function is: sin(x^2)"`.

Expected return: `"The function is: [1] 0.8414710 -0.7568025  0.4121185"`

Comment: Thanks, but no. It is part of the alist() sintaxis for as.function(). However, using this scheme its not important. I need to pass a function as argument, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
x <- eval(parse(text=args[1]))
f <- as.function(c(alist(x=),parse(text = "sin(x^2)")[[1]]))
cat("The function is:")
print(f(x))
```

Then

```
$ Rscript imp.R "c(1,2,3)" "sin(x^2)"
The function is:[1]  0.8414710 -0.7568025  0.4121185
```

However **AVOID PARSING ARBITRARY INPUT** since it is easy to inject malicious code that way. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391779/6912817